# Нарушенный порядок. Не могу разобраться с массивами

Tags: java, массивы

Дано целое число N, не превосходящее 1000. Далее следуют N целых чисел.

Порядок нарушен тогда, когда среди двух соседних элементов массива левый элемент больше правого.

Программа должна считать количество нарушенных порядков в массиве и выводить это количество на экран.

Sample Input 1:
5
2 4 1 9 7

Sample Output 1:
2

Мое решение валится с ошибкой "NumberFormatException"...
Что я делаю не правильно?

```
public class TestClass {
    static int count;
    static int lcount;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int [] a = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = in.nextInt();
        String []  m = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        int len = a.length;
        lcount = 1;
        while (lcount >0) {
            lcount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                int j = Integer.valueOf(m[i]);
                if (i < len - 1) {
                    int k = Integer.valueOf(m[i + 1]);
                    if (j > k) {
                        m[i + 1] = m[i];
                        count++;
                        lcount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int [] a = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = in.nextInt();

        int elementsNumb = getElementsNumb(a);

        System.out.println(elementsNumb);
    }

    private static int getElementsNumb(int[] array) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i-1] > array[i]) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Как-то у вас все сложно...
в метод getElementsNumb передаете свой массив, получаете количество нарушенных порядков. пользовательский ввод взял у вас, я думаю его подправите, если надо...

Answer (score 1):

В коде что-то странное происходит.

### NumberFormatException

Сначала Вы читаете `n` чисел:

```
int [] a = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = in.nextInt();
```

Потом эти числа нигде не используются. Вместо этого еще какая-то строка зачем-то считывается и дробится по пробелам:

```
String []  m = in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Судя по описанию формата, `in.nextLine()` вернет пустую строку, которая разделится на массив с одной пустой строкой. Далее при попытке преобразовать эту строку в число и возникает исключение.

**Решение:** Убрать массив `m` и его считывание, использовать везде массив `a`. Заодно избавитесь от `Integer.valueOf`.

### Логика

Непонятно зачем Вам `lCount` и цикл по нему. По условию нужно проверить нарушения порядка *только* между соседними элементами. Так что одного прохода по циклу должно быть достаточно. Присвоения `m[i+1] = m[i]` так же не нужно. Не уверен, впрочем, что это единственная ошибка в логике. Написал то, что увидел.

Еще, переменная `len` в нормальном ходе работы всегда равна `n`. Лучше везде использовать `n` или напрямую `a.length`.

### Вообще

Если возникает исключение при вызове метода, то нужно проверить все его аргументы. Т.е. если строка:

```
int j = Integer.valueOf(m[i]);
```

вызывает `NumberFormatException` первое, что нужно сделать это добавить перед ней вывод:

```
System.out.println("m[i] = "+m[i]);
int j = Integer.valueOf(m[i]);
```

И тогда будет понятно, что `m[i]` — пустая строка и можно будет отступить на шаг назад и посмотреть откуда `m` приходит. А именно заменить код:

```
String []  m = in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

На:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("line = "+line);
String[] m = line.split(" ");
System.out.println("m = "+Arrays.toString(m));
```

Если умеете пользоваться средствами отладки, то можно просто посмотреть значения переменных и не писать код для вывода.

Почитайте статью «[Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)». В принципе, в программе из 20 строк можно разобрать входные значения и результат для каждой строки.